# Pandas comparing specific rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe consisting of two columns winner and newcol2. Both columns contain the variables white black and draw. I want to compare each row in the column. For example if winner: white and newcol2: black return 1

```
  winner    newcol2
0  white     black
1  black     white
2  white     white
3  draw      white
4  black     draw

conditions1 = [
(x['winner'] == 'white'),
(x['winner'] == 'draw'), 
(x['winner'] == 'black')]
conditions2 = [
(x['newcol2'] == 'white'),
(x['newcol2'] == 'draw'),
(x['newcol2'] == 'black')]

x['result'] = np.select(conditions1, conditions2, default='null')
```

I've tried to solve my problem with the following code but Im getting true and false for variables that are and aren't equal

Comment: You have to paste your code too that you tried. SO we can help if you are facing issues with your code & explanation.

Comment: When do you want to return 1 when winner is white/black and newcol2 the other OR when both are the same value ?

Comment: I want to return 1 for the specific combination white/black. Then return 2 for the combination black/white and so on and so on

Answer (score 2):

As I understand, you want to assign a value to every unique combination of two columns in your DataFrame.

You can use this approach to create a dict with codes, or generate it with itertools, if there aren't all combinations in the dataframe.

```py
combs = set(zip(df['winner'], df['newcol2']))
codes = dict(zip(combs, range(len(combs))))
```

Use apply method to replace combinations in two columns with an encoded value:

```py
df['result'] = df.apply(lambda x: codes[x['winner'], x['newcol2']], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what all your conditions are other than the example you gave, but this will work:

```
In [23]: conditions = []


In [24]: for row in df.itertuples(): 
...:     if row.winner == 'white' and row.newcol2 == 'black': 
...:         conditions.append(1) 
...:     elif row.winner == 'black' and row.newcol2 == 'white': 
...:         conditions.append(1) 
...:     else: 
...:         conditions.append(0) 
...:                                                                        

In [25]: conditions                                                             
Out[25]: [1, 1, 0, 0, 0]

In [26]: df['conditions'] = conditions                                          

In [27]: df                                                                     
Out[27]: 
  winner newcol2  conditions
0  white   black           1
1  black   white           1
2  white   white           0
3   draw   white           0
4  black    draw           0
```

You can modify the code for whatever your conditions are